# Vite: How to import a CSS with dynamic path?

Tags: vite

How to make this import work?:

```
await import(`playground-elements/themes/${import.meta.env.VITE_THEME}.css`);
```

error:

```
"Failed to resolve module specifier 'playground-elements/themes/material.css'"
```

it works only if I use static path:

```
await import(`playground-elements/themes/material.css`);
```